# minimum degree of generators of a vanishing ideal of finite points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have finite set of points, for simplicity let us say they are in $\mathbb C^2$ (or the projective space $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$). So let these points be $P_1,P_2,\dots,P_n$. I want to compute the generator of the vanishing ideals of these points, say $I$, and from these I want to magically conclude what the minimum (total/homogenous) degree of a polynomial in $I$ will be. This will not be the minimum degree of the polynomials I get from taking the Gröbner basis will it? Can we say something about this degree if these points are in generic/general position?

Comment: In the affine case, after a homogeneous linear change of variables (which does not affect degrees), you may assume that the ideal is generated by two elements, $y-f(x), g(x)$ where $\deg f=n-1, \deg g=n$. In projective space, with the genericity assumption, it is easy too. The smallest degree will be the minimum $d$ such that $\binom{d+2}{2}>n$.

Comment: How did you get the inequality for the projective case? If the explanation is long, could you at least provide a reference? I want to also see how the genericity is used in these cases. Is there a general statement for other dimensional ambient spaces?

Comment: If you choose $d$ as I said, there will always be a hypersurface of that degree containing the points, it may not be the smallest if the points are not generic. Consider the natural map $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(d))\to H^0(\mathcal{O}_X(d))$ where $X$ is the union of points. The first has dimension $\binom{d+2}{2}$ and the latter $n$, so it has a non-zero kernel.

Comment: If you could post this as answer, I would gladly mark it as answered. But I would rather argue as simple as possible (without talking about $\mathcal O_X(d)$ which I am not so familiar with). For instance, you could argue this because this counts the number of monomials of forms of degree $d$ in $2$ variables, and for points in general position ($n$ of them) you will need this inequality for you to be able to solve $n$ system of linear equations. But I like your answer because this gives me a motivation to study twisting sheaves.